# Error MSB3025: using CruiseControl.net - Builds fine from command prompt

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I'm hoping someone has seen this error before. I'm using MSBuild with CruiseControl.Net to run the build for this project. When i run the build from the command prompt it actually builds without errors, but when i run it with CruiseControl.net i get the following error:

error MSB3025: The source file "C:\PE\PE-DEV\UIProjects\FolderName\" is actually a directory.  The "Copy" task does not support copying directories.

> 6 Warning(s)
>
> 1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:01:50.07

I have been doing a search and nothing with that error number shows up in google. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<msbuild>
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\PE\PE-DEV</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>Solution.sln</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=DeployDev;BuildMode=DRYRUN;CreatePackage=true /fileLogger /verbosity:normal</buildArgs>
    <targets>Build</targets>
    <timeout>900</timeout>
    <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>
```

This task works fine in other projects... If i use command prompt and run msbuild it works fine as well.

Comment: post the relevant portions of your build script.

Comment: Could you post your command line and your cc.net project conf please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was a tricky one, i was able to make the project work. The issue was the deploy build xml file had a typo somewhere and i was able to find the bug and fix it and now the project is building as it should.

Answer (score 1):

If it works when you run it from the command prompt (runs using your user account and permissions) and fails when running under CC (runs under whatever service account cc is running) it might be a permission issue. Try changing the account that cc.net runs under to your own account and see what happens.

Comment: I'm actually running this under the same account, so it doesn't seem to be permissions. Also it runs well for other projects that i have setup.